# Angularjs: how to show incremental counter (progress message) while ng-repeat is working?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

**Requirement**

Suppose, I have an array of `10000` length. While `ng-repeat` is repeating and showing the content of the list, meanwhile I need to show a progress message showing how many elements have created.

*Long story short* : *show progress message showing how far ng-repeat has reached*

**What I have done**

Here is a code that I have done (not working).

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope, $timeout) {

    $scope.list = []; /// list that is going to be repeated
    $scope.count = 10000; /// no of items in the list


    /// filling the list
    var templist = [];
    for (var index = 0; index < $scope.count; index++) {

        templist.push(index);
    }
    $scope.list = templist;

    ///  default msg of progress
    var progress = '0/' + $scope.count;

    /// function will be called when the the list will be getting rendered
    $scope.reportProgress = function (i) {
        console.log(i);
        setTimeout(function () {
            /// updating the progress message
            progress = i + "/" + $scope.count;
            $("#prog").html(progress);
        }, 1);
    }

})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="appCtrl">

        progress: <span id="prog"></span>

        <div ng-repeat="i in list track by $index">
            {{i}} {{reportProgress($index)}}
            <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you try using ng-bind to update the progress, instead of manually modifying a DOM? Also what do you mean it is not working? Is it slow to update or not updating at all?

Comment: Edit : I have created a fiddle, which updates the progress using ng-bind. This is the link - http://jsfiddle.net/Vamshhi/3mjpyq0s/

Comment: @Vamsi many thanks for the effort. I run the fiddle and found that the `ng-repeat` is finished but the counter is still showing a running count down. **I need to show the progress of ng-repeat. if the ng-repeat is finshed then the progress should show completed status e.g. 10000/10000**

Comment: It will be a intense task on browser to run ng-repeat for 10000 values, I would always avoid it. If you really want to show a progress for such iterations, I would suggest you to avoid manipulating DOM (changing the progress value) for each iteration and do it for some 100s, so that it would update the DOM quickly. I updated my fiddle, to reflect the same. Here is the link : http://jsfiddle.net/Vamshhi/3mjpyq0s/3/

Comment: @Vamsi great work and many thanks. you are life saver. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your html you can have something like this: `ng-if="showProgress(i)"`

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list track by $index">
   <div ng-if="showProgressBar(i)">
        <!-- progress bar for each {{item}} -->
   </div>
 </div>
```

In your scope, you can pass the `id` or other `value`.

```
$scope.showProgressBar = function(i){
      $scope.list.forEach(function(item){
          if (item._id === i.id){
            item.progress = !item.progress;
          }
      });
};
```

Comment: Actually, I want to show the progress of `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--PROBLEMATIC CODE -->

<div ng-repeat="i in list track by $index">
    {{i}} {{reportProgress($index)}}
    <hr/>
</div>
```

The probem with this code is that on every digest cycle, every item in the list will report progress.

Instead imbed the `reportProgress` call in the link function of a custom directive.

```
<div ng-repeat="i in list track by $index">
    {{i}}
    <hr report-expn="reportProgress($index)" />
</div>
```

JS

```
app.directive("reportExpn", function () {
    return {
        link: function(scope,elem, attrs) {
            scope.$eval(attrs.reportExpn);
        }
    };
});
```

This way the `reportProgress` function will be invoked only once per list item when the `report-expn` directive is linked.

Comment: @georogeawg thanks for answering but the problem still persist. I did as you mentioned but what happens is that the counter starts incrementing after the `ng-repeat` finish its work.

Comment: may be scope.$evalAsync() will be faster than scope.$eval as the earlier executes even before the browser renders it. Please do correct me if I'm wrong